# Gmail: Automatically detecting all caps in incoming messages, converting to bold

Tags: gmail

So I have a senior colleague who regularly misuses all caps to emphasize points. This is annoying to see regularly--especially in reviews of my work--so I am curious if there is a Gmail add on or customization possible to change the words in ALL CAPS to **all caps** before it shows up in my inbox.

This only needs to work on plain text.

Comment: You cannot change the text in incoming emails. Either you could manipulate the text & then save it to PDF or Doc; or a custom javascript to just change the display on your browser.

Comment: Welcome. Software recommendations are off-topic here.Try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to call out messages with all caps, maybe you could create a filter with the text you are looking for and then have that filter do something special.

Another option here is to use another email client instead of gmail to view your messages, using IMAP or POP3.

Or write a bot that reads the email via those servers and makes the notification/changes there.